# sqlite - autoincrement field generates negative numbers

Tags: sqlite

I have a strange issue with SQLite.
If I run a query and add a record my autoinc field functions properly.
Numbers go in sequence.

However, If I use the grid and the dbnavigator to add the record directly inside the grid , the autoinc field suddenly does not follow the sequence of numbers but adds -1 to the newly added record.

Is this a bug or some kind of normal behavior that I am unaware off ?

Comment: SQLite itself does not have components named "grid" or "dbnavigator".

Comment: that is within my application....

Comment: Probably not sqlite. Maybe you're storing a the integer value sqlite is returning into too small an integer field. For example a 4-byte number into an integer you allocated as a 2-byte int.  In that case some subset of the 4-byte numbers would have bits that overrun the 2-byte field, and some would overwrite the 2-byte sign flag with a 1-bit, causing the value to be interpreted as negative when something refers to it. Or alternatively if you used a format specifier in a print statement that is not large enough to accommodate one of the integer values, it could misinterpret the value.